# Beautiful Soup return none object for non-dynamic content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests as requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
        'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0, no-cache'
    }
htmlFile=requests.get('https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/1', headers=headers).text
sou=BeautifulSoup(htmlFile,"html.parser")
re = sou.find(class_="leftContainer").findAll(class_="bookTitle")
print(re)
```

The content is not dynamic,no need for JS or anything like that.
So why sometimes None object return?
while loop who trying again and again can solve the problem but that's not really a solution.

Comment: I actually can't reproduce this error on my machine having run it maybe ~ 50 times. How rare is sometimes?

Comment: I only received after about 170 times,maybe the server is limiting the number of requests?

Comment: I got it at around 100th request. The response code was 504, which means it is server's problem which probably means you are making too many requests at the same time

Comment: Thank,how did you get the response code? is there a function in  beautiful soup that supports this?

Comment: Well, you have to learn about requests first. the `requests.get` method returns `Response` object which has `status_code` field. You had to at least print it before directly taking `text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error**

After reproducing the issue, I deducted that the server returns a different
response after 100-200 requests. The difference between a standard, parseable response and the one that does not have the data to scrape is that the different one is given as an occasional error page and returns code **[504]**. This code essentially means the server timed out or errored, so a default HTML page is returned without the books, and thus an error in the code is brought.

Snippet from Test Case Response from Error:

```html
<h1>
                            Goodreads request took too long.
                        </h1>
<p>
                            The latest request to the Goodreads servers took too long to respond. We have been notified of the issue and are looking into it.
                        </p>
```

**Solution**

This can be due to chance or to an imposed limit to prevent scrapers from using too many system resources, but this is more likely just a normal server-side error and is *unavoidable*. Simply include a try/except catch in the case of a bad response, and retry the request again!